# Django - UpdateView does not save to DB

Tags: django, post, django-models, django-forms

My UpdateView does not save to local DB upon clicking Submit button.

**views.py**

```
class BHA_UpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'bha_test.html'
    context_object_name = 'bha'
    model = BHA_overall
    success_url = reverse_lazy('well_list')
    pk_url_kwarg = 'pk_alt'
    form_class = BHA_overall_Form

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        pk = self.kwargs.get(self.pk_url_kwarg)
        api = get_well_api(self.request)
        current_bha = BHA_List.objects.filter(well=api, id=pk)[0]
        return current_bha
```

**forms.py**

```
class BHA_overall_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = BHA_overall
        fields = '__all__'
```

**models.py**

```
class BHA_List(models.Model):
    well = models.ForeignKey(WellInfo, 'CASCADE', related_name='bha_list')
    bha_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class BHA_overall(models.Model):
    bha_number = models.ForeignKey(BHA_List, 'CASCADE', related_name='bha_overall')
    drill_str_name = models.CharField(max_length=111)
    depth_in = models.CharField(max_length=111)
```

**bha_test.html**

```
<form method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit" class='btn btn-primary' value="Submit">
</form>
```

Someone told me that in UpdateView, the model and the form should refer to the same thing. So I did that, but its still not working. Here is my [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51488989/django-updateview-form-does-not-save/51489017#51489017):

How can I modify my code so that my form will save to my DB?

**Update:**

`BHA_List` has a list of BHA objects. Each BHA objects has many child objects, `BHA_overall` being one of it.

I have url that looks like this:

```
re_path(r'^bha/(?P<pk_alt>[-\w]+)$', base_views.BHA_UpdateView.as_view(), name='bha')
```

Ideally, `pk_url_kwarg = 'pk_alt'` should look up objects inside `BHA_List`, and navigate to a page where you can update information about that specific object inside `BHA_List`. The fields you can update include the fields in `BHA_overall`.

So it looks like this:

```
You can now edit [ BHA 2 ]: # url = .../bha/2

    BHA Overall Information - 
    Drill_str_name: []
    Depth_in: []
    ...

    Other Child Model - 
    other_field: []
    other_field: []
```

I need `pk_url_kwarg = 'pk_alt'` to query `BHA_List` instances to generate unique `url`, and I need `BHA_overall_Form` to display input fields where users can edit, and save that user input to DB. What other CBV should I use here then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `get_object` method returns `BHA_list` object. But your view and form's model is `BHA_overall`. So `get_object` should also return `BHA_overall` instance which you want to update:

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    pk = self.kwargs.get(self.pk_url_kwarg)
    api = get_well_api(self.request)
    bha_number = BHA_List.objects.filter(well=api, id=pk)[0]
    current_bha = BHA_overall.objects.filter(bha_number=bha_number)[0]
    return current_bha
```

Comment: I see the source of error. But that gives me an another trouble. I need `pk_url_kwarg` to lookup items in `BHA_List` model instances. That's why I had to override `get_object()`. If I don't override `get_object()`, `pk_url_kwarg` will search items in `BHA_overall` model instances, and that's not what I want. How can I resolve this issue then?

Comment: @EricKim Do you need to get `BHA_overall` by `BHA_list` object? It this case you can use two queries: `bha_number = BHA_List.objects.filter(well=api, id=pk)[0]` and `current_bha = BHA_overall.objects.filter(bha_number=bha_number)[0]`.

Comment: No that's not what I need. The only problem is that `pk_url_kwarg` should look up `BHA_List`, while all the other things need to get `BHA_overall` objects. If it wasn't for `pk_url_kwarg`, I would not need to override `get_object()`. Is there any way to trick Django to change the behavior of only `pk_url_kwarg`?

Comment: @EricKim Looks like you misunderstanding how `UpdateView` works. It's get specific object by some kwargs and update it. `UpdateView` is not supposed to get one object and update another.

Comment: what CBV would support such features then?

Comment: @EricKim Can you tell what exactly you want to do? Why you need to retreive one object and update another?

Comment: please check the update. And thanks for trying to help me out. really appreciate it

Comment: @EricKim you are welcome. I suppose you'd better to use inline formsets for this. Check example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45278491/inline-formset-factory-update-view