# Django - force pk_url_kwarg to query other model instances

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Consider the following code:

**views.py**

```
class BHA_UpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = BHA_overall
    pk_url_kwarg = 'pk_alt'
    form_class = BHA_overall_Form
```

To my understanding, `pk_url_kwarg = 'pk_alt'` will query and return instances of `model = BHA_overall`.

Is there any way that I can force `pk_url_kwarg` to query 
 & return other model instances defined in `models.py` (like `model = other_model`), while having my `get_object()` method to return objects in `model = BHA_overall`? What CBV should I use (I think `UpdateView` is not a good choice in this case)?

++ I'm trying to make a page that allows users to manage information about the product they use. So, ultimately I will implement forms, and the user input needs to be saved in DB

++ I need `pk_url_kwarg = 'pk_alt'` to query other models and generate url. But I still need `get_object()` method to return objects in `model = BHA_overall` to generate form fields on the user side.

Comment: You mean you want to make page for managing products objects (from user who logged in), right?

Comment: @seuling yes, for that, I need multiple models.

Comment: Then I think you should use CBV from `Product` model. First, use `ListView` for Product model for listing all products. (For just logged in uses). Second, use `UpdateView` for product model to update the product

Comment: @seuling That's not the issue I have. The specific issue I'm struggling now is forcing `pk_url_kwarg` to query a specific model from a list of multiple models provided

Comment: I can't understand. You just can just use `get_object()` then.

Comment: So I did that, but if I do that, it won't save to DB. please check out this question I posted before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51491229/django-updateview-does-not-save-to-db

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176684/discussion-between-seuling-and-eric-kim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding you need a django form generated from BHA_overall, but the data should be saved to AnotherModel right?

I will propose 2 solutions to this problem, Choose what best fits you.

1. Multiple views:
   Have multiple views for the task, What I mean is create a view which creates the form for the frontend using BHA_overall, you can create both Create and Update view this way and update view's initial could be overwritten so form will have expected value when editing. And now post the data to another view which handles the post data. This view can have your AnotherModel doing its thing.
2. Using Django Form:
   If you dont like having multiple views, You can keep things simple by creating a form yourself. Create a DjangoForm with the same fields you want to show to the user and use it in to create your own views, Now you wont need BHA_overall and use your AnotherModel to save datal.

Comment: hey, would you mind answering this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51528054/django-multiple-models-in-one-page. I've tried to use Forms, but it won't do the job when I want to update the existing model instances. Regarding using multiple views, I really have no clue. I searched internet, but couldn't find an example that deals with this

Comment: Sure, I wil do.