# Django - multiple models in one page

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a model that looks like this:

**models.py**

```
class BHA_List(models.Model):
    well = models.ForeignKey(WellInfo, 'CASCADE', related_name='bha_list')
    bha_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class BHA_Drill_Bit(models.Model):
    bha_number = models.ForeignKey(BHA_List, 'CASCADE', related_name='bha_drill_bit')
    bit_type = models.CharField(max_length=111)  

class BHA_overall(models.Model):
    bha_number = models.ForeignKey(BHA_List, 'CASCADE', related_name='bha_overall')
    drill_str_name = models.CharField(max_length=111)

class BHA_Motor(models.Model):
    bha_number = models.ForeignKey(BHA_List, 'CASCADE', related_name='bha_drill_bit')
    motor_type = models.CharField(max_length=111)
```

`BHA_List` is a parent model, and the rest are child models related by `ForeignKey`. The screenshot is the page I want to create

[image]

So, I want to generate a base page using one of the instances in `model = BHA_List`. In this page, I want to edit model instances that are related to `BHA_List` by `ForeignKey` relationship.

I currently have a view that looks like this, but its wrong:

```
class BHA_UpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = BHA_List
    pk_url_kwarg = 'pk_alt'
    form_class = BHA_overall_Form
```

By setting `model = BHA_List`, I was able to get one of the instances in `BHA_List`, and generate url from it. Right now my `views` correctly return one of the instances in `BHA_List`: `BHA 1`

I attempted to edit child models by setting `form_class = BHA_overall_Form`. But this doesn't do anything, though it displayed form fields on the user side. After editing and clicking `Submit` button, the changes are not saved in DB. Someone pointed out that this is because my model in `UpdateView` and form does not match, as I set `model = BHA_List`, but `form_class = BHA_overall_form`.

How can I resolve this issue? Someone else also pointed out using multiple views, but I don't really know how to do it, as I'm very new to Django. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so that you know. UpdateView can be used if you want to update a single row in one table. When you set model = BHA_LIST you are saying Django. Hey, Django I want to update this model so render me a form with the fields from this table. You can do this by just setting fields attr on the model or use a form like you did which will customize which fields are shown. Now the good thing about allowing to set our own form is. Though we create a modelForm we can also add extra fields inside it. Now your BHAOverallForm should look like this to accommodate all the fields you need.

forms.py

```
class BHAOverallForm(forms.ModelForm):
    well = models.ForeignKey(WellInfo, 'CASCADE', related_name='bha_list')
    bha_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    bit_type = models.CharField(max_length=111
    drill_str_name = models.CharField(max_length=111)
    motor_type = models.CharField(max_length=111)

    class Meta:
        model = BHAList
```

you can use this form inside your form like you do now. You can also add clean_field to add validations. Now coming to the update part. your views should look like this

views.py

```
class BHAUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = BHAList
    form_class = BHAOverallForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        super(BHAUpdateView, self).form_valid(form) # save BHAList to the DB
        bha_list = form.instance
        bha_drill_bit = bha_list.bhadrillbit_set.first() # assuming you have only one drill_bit per list, if you need more modify your question accordingly.
        bha_drill_bit.bit_type = form.cleaned_data.get("bit_type)
        bha_drill_bit.save()

        # you can do the same for other models as well.
```